# Mechanics of a disk

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have an interesting problem. A disk travels in air at velocity v1. It travels in glass (assuming that the disk can enter the glass without breaking it) at velocity v2. v1 is greater than v2. The disk has radius r.

Lets say that it hits the glass at a particular angle a. Then the part of the disk that enters the glass will travel at v2, the part outside the glass will still travel at v1. This will cause the disk to deviate from its initial path and bend inwards. The opposite would happen when the disc exits the glass on the other side.

What will be the total angle that the disk will deviate from its initial path?

What would be a good way to approach solving this question?

Comment: This look very similar to [refraction of light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction). But shouldn't the disk break if a part of it moves at $v1$ and the other moves at $v2$

Comment: I don't see any reason that the disk's path needs to bend, given what you've said. Also, it is not clear what this disk is like. If it's rigid, its parts can't move at different speeds except for rotation. If it's not rigid, you need to tell us how it handles stress. What what is the nature of this magic glass such that the disk always travels at a certain speed? 

It seems like you read about Fermat's principle somewhere. If you'd like to ask a question about it, maybe it would be better just to ask about Fermat's principle directly.

Comment: @udiboy Yes. I was thinking of refraction of light. But I was thinking maybe from a pure particle perspective. I thought of a disk because the photon travelling at c should compress to a plane (?) due to length contraction. It is just a fleeting thought I had, so I thought I'd ask a question here. I thought the difference in velocity of the part of the photon in the medium 2 and its greater velocity in medium 1 would create a moment which would make it bend towards the normal. This was my thought. Please feel to criticise the thought if its wrong. I only seek a better understanding, that's all

Comment: @Physicsn00b, I suppose you are thinking of a photon as a sphere(or a disk probably) at the quantum level. In fact, it is neither, even when it behaves as a particle. During refraction, it almost certainly behaves as a wave, so you trying to analyse this behavior with a disk of finite dimensions will definitely lead to a very strange result.

Comment: Perhaps the intention is to regard the disk as flexible and the "glass" perhaps as some kind of special fluid which allows the disk to pass through at a constant speed different to its speed in air.

Comment: @Henry 5. That was exactly the intention. Light or no light, I still thought this was an interesting question. The disk has no rigidity and can bend. The glass slab is a special fluid which the disk enters at a particular angle and exits at the same angle. How could one calculate the angle of deviation (if it is possible) inside the glass slab. Even if we consider the photon as a wave, there should be a point where half the wave (photon) is in the liquid and the other half is outside. I guess I just wanted to try and see if there was another way to get to Snell's Laws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are thinking about LIGHT the 'conservative answer' would be:

For this experment photon behaves as a wave, it doesnt have actual size, and so the only thing that will happen is that the wave will stretch its lenght, but the photon itself will not stretch as it has no diameter.

Comment: Some people may talk that as a wave photon has an infinite size. Personally i dont like this duality about light nor this quantum approach either.

Comment: I thought about this more. I agree with you. The photon would behave as a wave. When the photon is incident at the surface of a liquid, it has two paths it can take. It can either be reflected at the same angle as the angle of incidence or it can be refracted through the liquid. It's like a beam splitter or Young's double slit experiment. As long as we cannot determine the path the photon took, it should behave as a wave. Do you think this interpretation applying Quantum principles is correct? It would be interesting to construct a single photon interference experiment involving refraction...

Comment: I think its correct. But honestly im not the best person to answer you about Quantum principles.

Comment: In my opinion what you would see is that the probability zone of the photon would stretch as it bypass the glass and become assimetric from an outsider perspective (if you could see a probability zone).. in both 'entering the glass' and 'exiting' it. Experimenting measuring the photon you would only see it when it was out or already in the glass, never in between the two.